# Send mail using Amazon SQS and Sendgrid

Tags: amazon-web-services, sendgrid, amazon-sqs

Which one is the best way to send mail using Amazon SQS and Sendgrid?
I am new for Amazon SQS and I am bit confused between two scenarios.

Scene 1:
Take mutliple emails and add to Queue on one message and send multiple email as array at a same.

Scene 2:
Take single email and add each to Queue in different message and send single email at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of the options. 
But, the optimised way of sending emails is multiple emails in one API call. That will improve the performance.